# How can I find closest element when all I have is HTML string X?

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I need to make a workaround for a link bug in Swiper JS using `onClick(swiper,e)`.

`swiper`: Is the entire swiper-container
`e`: is a MouseEvent where the property `target` contains HTML string, e.g. `<div class="start-time">16:00</div>`

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <a href="abc" target="_blank">
        <div class="start-time">16:00</div>
        <div class="flag"><img ...></div>
        <div class="name col-4">Buritos</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to prevent default Swiper behaviour, find the link and open a new window. This code is not working, but pseudocode for how  I want it

```js
    onClick: function(swiper, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let target = $(e.target); // HTML is now jQuery
        let slide = target.closest('swiper-slide'); //Not working
        let link = slide.find('a').attr('href');
        window.open(link);
    },
```

I'm stuck at finding the parent `swiper-slide` when the user clicks any element inside the slide. I thought `target.closest('swiper-slide')` would do the trick, but it didn't.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: meaning finding the `swiper-wrapper`?

Comment: What element is `e.target`?

Comment: You should add dot before 'swiper-slide' in `closest()` to match class: `.swiper-slide`.

Comment: Right you are Yariash. I could kick myself now :-/

Comment: Are you sure it is the right thing to do though? Hacking through a link bug? The javascript you are using does exactly the same as the link href + target does... You could also directly change those attributes! What if the user does not click to follow the link? Like using tab key or other ways to navigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
onClick: function(swiper, e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var hyperlink = $(e.target).closest('a');

    window.open(hyperlink.attr('href'));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.parents()` to traverse more than one level up from the clicked element and pass a selector to find the one you want like this:

```
onClick: function(swiper, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let target = $(e.target); // HTML is now jQuery
    let slide = target.parents('.swiper-slide')[0];
    let link = slide.find('a').attr('href');
    window.open(link);
},
```

Comment: `[0]` will return a DOMElement, so `slide.find()` will return an error. If `closest()` didn't work for the OP, `parents()` won't either.

Comment: If you just need the HREF why don't you just use $(e.target).closest('a').attr('href') ?